# How can I add an image to my listview

Tags: android, listview

Hello I wanto to add an image to my listview.
How can I do this?
xml code
list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java code

I tried to use the code in the comment but it doesn't work

```
private void showEmployee(String json){
    try {
        JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
        String ref = c.getString("Reference");
        String loginr = c.getString("Login");
        String prix = c.getString("Prix");
        String quantite = c.getString("Quantite");
        String prixT = c.getString("PrixT");
        String dateCom = c.getString("DateCom");
        editRef.setText(ref);
        editLogin.setText(loginr);
        editprixu.setText(prix);
        editQt.setText(quantite);
        editprix.setText(prixT);
        editdate.setText(dateCom);}
```

catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to try obtain at least a small knowledge of Android development.

Answer (score 0):

I just know you should use Adapter. Just like:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
...
}
```

then, just use it like:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
```

You can override getView() like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {

    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(context);
    }
    Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(context).load((String)getItem(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).error(R.drawable.error).resize(450,600).into(view);
    return view;
    /*
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(450, 600));
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bms[position]); // Load image into ImageView
    return imageView;
    */
}
```

Add your layout in this function. Maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

follow this example[listView with image](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)